# When an image is referenced more than once in DOM/Javascript variable will it be cached only Once?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

If an image is referenced more than once in DOM and saved in multiple JS variables, will the image be cached only once?

Comment: Yes, the variables share a reference to the same image node, unless you cloned it. And the JS really doesn't have any effect on the browser cache, if that's what you meant by caching.

Comment: Thanks for the response. To clarify. in JS when I have something like this: img  = new Image(); img.src = 'foo.jpeg', and if in DOM I reference foo.jpeg, will foo.jpeg be reference the image cached by JS?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "cached by JS". In JS, you have a reference to an image node, and that node will continue to exist as long as there's some reference to it somewhere. It doesn't really have any impact on the binary data that comprises the actual image. So if you're wondering if the image data will be downloaded again so that you end up with the same image in memory, the answer is no, unless perhaps you're requesting the same image from a different location on the server.